# Have iPhone App communicate with an OSX app

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos

Is there an **easy** way to make an iPhone application communicate with a Mac app?  By communicate, I mean able to control certain things within the mac application, like control a character on the monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNetService` and `NSNetServiceBrowser` are the Cocoa classes for broadcasting and connecting to Bonjour services.  I'd recommend starting with those.

Answer (score 0):

Networking isn't easy!

The above answer by Dave is great if you can make the assumption that your phone and app/computer will be on the same network (behind router, firewall, etc).  Otherwise, you'll need an external host (at a FQDN (URL) that both the phone and PC can reach) to manage the communication between the 2.  At that point, you are making a web-based communications layer :(